# Reward Function for automated parking autonomous Robots

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, robotics, reward

I'm implementing a reinforcement learning task, to solve a parking task for autonomous robots. So basically, the idea of the task is to start at a certain Point in front of the parking spot and drive to a pose without colliding with obstacles. The Agent has reached the goal if the a given Position and a Heading angle of the robot matches the goal pose.

I Have actually a lot of Problems shaping a Reward Function to solve this task. So I ask you guys, to help me with this. What I need a Reward Function depending on the following:

- **(Distance reward)**
  The closer the robot is to the target, the higher the reward
- **(Orientation reward)** The smaller the tolerance of the heading angle to the angle of the target position, the higher the reward
- **(Speed reward)** The slower the speed when approaching the target position, the higher the reward

My current Reward function looks like this:

```
    current_distance = self.get_euclidean_distance(current_position, desire_position)
    self.distance_reward = (-1)* current_distance/self.max_dist_to_targ

    # Heading Reward. 0: indicates vertical parking, -1: means reverse parking state
    heading_angle = abs(current_heading_angle - target_angle)
    if heading_angle > 0 and heading_angle < np.pi:
        self.heading_angle_reward = -1 * abs(heading_angle - np.pi/2) / np.pi
    else:
        self.heading_angle_reward = -2 * abs(heading_angle - (3*np.pi)/2) / (2*np.pi - 1)
        
    # Goal Reward
    self.goal_reward = 0
    if current_distance <= cp.pose_tolerance and heading_angle <= np.radians(cp.heading_angle_tolerance):
        self.goal_reward = 150

    # Collistion Penalty
    if not self.is_near_by_an_object2(beams_coords, current_trans_vel):
        self.collision_penalty = 0
    else:
        self.collision_penalty = -10

    reward = 10*((1 - w) * self.distance_reward + w * self.heading_angle_reward) +\
            10*self.goal_reward + 10* self.collision_penalty
```

I would be very happy if someone can suggest me what is wrong with the function and how to implement the velocity reward!
Thank you guys.

Comment: Could you post an MRE? There are a few possible errors that could mess up your class, but without context, it is hard to tell. On first glance, should reward not be prepended with self. ?

Comment: Hi! Im really new on this topic.  Where do I find the MRE? the Reward is being return (I Edit it allreardy! I you tell me what do you need to better understandig I would provide you (I Guess) Thank you!

Comment: An MRE is an piece of example code anyone can copy/paste and run with minimal modification. This helps people in analyzing your code.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example